# Angular 4 and Spring Rest: How to post FormData containing File and model object in a single request

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I would like to send a File object along with custom model object in a single request.

```
let formData:FormData = new FormData();
let file = this.fileList[0];
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
formData.append('address', JSON.stringify(customObj));
...
this.http.post(fileServeUrl, formData)
```

My backend is in Spring Rest as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileServe",
            produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<Image> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile imageData, @RequestPart("address") Address address) throws IOException {...}
```

I was able to receive the data if I pass simple String along with File though.

```
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
formData.append('address', addressText);
```

Backend

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileServe",
            produces = {"application/json"},
            consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    ResponseEntity<Image> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile imageData, @RequestPart("address") String addressText) throws IOException {...}
```

I tried @RequestBody for my custom object but even that didn't work. Any advise please.

Comment: For now, tried to pass a string in json format and used GSON to convert to my custom object - this way I don't have to send multiple parameters as part of my argument list                                  
`ResponseEntity<Image> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile imageData, @RequestPart("addressObjectInJson") String addressObjectInJson)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with @Requestbody and @RequestPart annotation is that spring use the HttpMessageConverter to take convert the incoming json message into the your object. As you send form data with a file and a text value spring can not convert it into your object. I am afraid you have to pass the value of address seperatetly.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileupload", headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"), method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<AjaxResponseBody> upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String postCode) {

    AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            Address address = new Address();
            address.setName(name);
            result.setMsg("ok");
            return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponseBody>(result, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<AjaxResponseBody>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Expept if you find a way your client app send a file with MimeType of image/jpg and and an address  of application/json which allow spring to parse the json and map to your Address object which i couldn't do it.